# Wiremock stub receive connection refused in second call in second class

Tags: integration-testing, stub, wiremock

I am stubbing and http call in my integration test twice by using wiremock scenario states. If I make http request in same class then everything works good but in my case second call is made by different class/thread in my application and it receives connection refused. How I stub request is:

```
 stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/user/" + userId))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    .withBody(jsonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(user))))
```

Why am I getting this error in second call?